# ¿Es posible hacer una pagina responsive sin CSS o Javascript?

Tags: html, html5, web

Me encuentro trabajando en un proyecto que requiere de una web que solo puede estar en archivo HTML5 (no puedo subir archivos CSS ni Javascript). Necesito que la misma sea responsive para diferentes tipos de pantallao mismo en caso de no tener la web en pantalla completa. ¿Es posible esto?

Comment: Puedes usar algún CMS como wordpress y un maquetador visual como Elementor. Con estas 2 opciones evitas hacer tu el css.

Comment: Sin js si, sin css no, salvo que pongas el css en el html (inline) pero algunas cosas tampoco podras hacerlas responsivas asi

Comment: No esta diciendo que no lo quiere hacer, esta diciendo que no puede subir archivos css o js y lo que dices si los sube

Answer (score 0):

sin js se puede, pero no puedes sin css, actualmente, html no cuenta con propiedades que permitan la correcta implementacion de una pagina web responsiva. Ahora, si no puedes subir archivos css, en html existe el tag style, en este puedes meter el codigo css directo en en el html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 2000px) {
      .heading-primary {
        color: blue;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
      .heading-primary {
        color: red;
      }
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="heading-primary">Title Here</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

hice un code pen donde puedes probarlo https://codepen.io/danildzambrana/pen/dydpjoj?editors=1000

> https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style